# How to automatically generate OpenAPI specification for AWS Lambda functions connected to API Gateway using SST?

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, openapi, sst, serverless-stack

I am currently developing a serverless application using Serverless Stack (SST) in a Node.js and TypeScript environment. My application involves AWS Lambda functions that are connected to an API Gateway. I want to generate OpenAPI specifications for my API endpoints automatically.

I've been looking into using tools like Tsoa or AWS CDK, but haven't found a straightforward way to integrate them with SST. I understand that AWS API Gateway has built-in support for OpenAPI, but I'm not sure how to leverage that with SST.

Does anyone have experience or insights on how I could automatically generate the OpenAPI specification using SST, or any guidance on the tools or methods I could use to achieve this?

Comment: When you say OpenAPI spec, are you expecting something like a Swagger documentation? Postman Collection?

Comment: I think so, I assume that I need Specification to let me implement them using swagger.

basically, I need to generate API spec for my lambda functions.  something like this:

openapi: 3.0.3
info:
  version: 1.0.0
  title: Simple Artist API
  description: A simple API to illustrate OpenAPI concepts

paths:
  /artists:
    post:
      description: Lets a user post a new artist
      requestBody:
        required: true
        content:
          application/json:
            schema:
              $ref: '#/components/schemas/Artist'